# Unknown Behavior of C program with variable integer array

Tags: arrays, c

I have the following programming:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int check = 0;
    int size_of_arr;
    int int_arr[size_of_arr];//Line 1
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &size_of_arr);// Line 2
    for (int dummy = 0; dummy < size_of_arr; dummy++)
    {
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", &int_arr[dummy]);
    }
    printf("Input Success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The program exists without taking input, but if Line 1 and Line 2 are interchanged, then the program successfully takes the input.

I am unable to understand why this is happening?

Comment: `int int_arr[size_of_arr];`  is a VLA (Varaible-length array valid since C99), the problem is that you are not providing an initial value to `size_of_arr`, using an uninitialized variable is UB. Always prefer a real constant value if you know the number of elements before hand, i.e. `enum {size_of_arr = 42};` In this case it seems that you want to get the size from an user input, then you need to move the `fscanf` before the definition of the array.

Comment: Compiling the program with warnings enabled should provide sufficient clues: `warning: variable 'size_of_arr' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Why it is a warning (see Cheatah comment)  and not an error meaning that the program exits with a return value 0?

Comment: @Kumar To be honest, I don't know on what basis gcc classifies an issue as a warning or as an error, IMO it should be an error.

Comment: OT: `printf("Input Success\n");` how do you know that? you didn't check the result of `fscanf`.

Comment: @Kumar UB means that the behavior is undefined. The syntax is still completely fine, so it should compile. You need to set some option like `-Werror` in gcc if you want to report warnings as errors. **Always enable warnings and fix them**

Comment: @DavidRanieri It is just a flag for me—nothing in particular. I have used the above snippet for my other code. I get you that the message is not good in context, but everyone has a different meaning of success. ;)

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Using an uninitialized object is not undefined behavior. Per C 2018 6.2.4 6 and 7, it produces an indeterminate value. There is a clause in the C standard that makes some use of uninitialized objects undefined behavior, but it does not apply in this code. C 2018 6.3.2.1 says the behavior is undefined when the value of an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration is used and the object could have been declared with `register`, which means its address is not taken. Since `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &size_of_arr);` takes the address of `size_of_arr`, that clause does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `size_of_arr`, so it causes undefined behavior

If you put line 1 before line 2, then you're creating an array with a size of `size_of_arr`, but because `size_of_arr`  is uninitialized, it will cause some undefined behavior.

`int int_arr[size_of_arr];//Line 1`

But if put line 2 before line 1, then you're assigning a value to `size_of_arr`

`fscanf(stdin, "%d", &size_of_arr);// Line 2`

And only now you create the array, so no undefined behavior.

Comment: But if that is undefined then why does the program just "warn" and doesn't show an error?

Comment: how does "undefined" related to compiler errors? Compiler errors are reported when the program is ill-formed, i.e. has syntax errors, and UB is a logical "error"

Comment: @phuclv: Undefined behavior is not limited to just “logical” errors. Per the note in C 2018 3.4.3, “Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).” A variety of undefined behavior causes can occur due to ill-formed source code, not just program execution.

Comment: There is no such thing as “an array with a size of undefined behavior.” That phrase does not make any sense.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But what about an array with a negative size?  AFAICT the only constraint on the expression denoting the size of a variable-length array is that it must be of "integer type", which doesn't preclude negative values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: An array with a negative size is an array with a negative size. It is not an array with a size of undefined behavior. The size is negative, not undefined. The definition of the array may have undefined behavior, but “an array with a size of undefined behavior” is a nonsensical phrase. No kind of “behavior,” defined or not, is the size of an array. E.g., you cannot have “an array of size polite behavior.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil True.  I'm not disagreeing with that at all.  But common sense seems to indicate that an array with negative size should be some form of UB.  Since the size is indeterminate here, it could be negative.  So there seems to be at least the possibility of invoking UB here, but I can't find support for that in the C 11 standard.